# Remote PerformanceCounter throws exception

Tags: .net, performancecounter

We have a problem querying custom performance counters from some machines in .NET

Some of those counter have base counters most don't(NumberOfItems64).
These counters work fine on all machines, meaning the categories, counters and instances are shown and we also see values in local perfmon.

In addition to the services writing the counters there is a site(impersonated to a user with *perfcounter read rights*) reading them. There are two users with the same rights but for different machines.

This works in the following constellations:

```
Dev-PC(User A)     - Dev-PC  (Domain1)
Dev-PC(User A)     - Server1 (Domain2) 
WebServer1(User A) - Server1 (Domain2)
WebServer2(User B) - Server1 (Domain2)
```

Sadly the following does not work at all:

```
Dev-PC(User B)     - Server2-n (Domain2) 
WebServer1(User B) - Server2-n (Domain2)
WebServer2(User B) - Server2-n (Domain2)
```

The exception is:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 
The Counter layout for the Category specified is invalid, a counter of the type:  
AverageCount64, AverageTimer32, CounterMultiTimer, CounterMultiTimerInverse,   
CounterMultiTimer100Ns, CounterMultiTimer100NsInverse, 
RawFraction, or SampleFraction has to be immediately followed by any of the base
counter  types: AverageBase, CounterMultiBase, RawBase or SampleBase.
at System.Diagnostics.CategorySample.GetCounterDefinitionSample(String counter)
at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter.NextSample()
at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter.NextValue()
```

This does not make much sense since the counter is of type *NumberOfItems64*!?

When I debugged it locally, I noticed that all of the PerformanceCounter properties throw exceptions in quick watch! What's wrong?

I was assured it has nothing to do with user rights(I had it checked a couple of times now)

Does anyone know this problem or does anything come to mind? 
I'm stuck, any help is highly appreciated!

Cheers

Fab

Comment: It's possible that the performance counter area of your registry has become corrupt. You may want to run the [lodctr /r](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490926.aspx) command to try and fix that.